# Numpy only doesn't work in one of my specific github folder

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, github, import, rename

I don't understand why numpy won't work in my github folder but works out of it.

```
~$ echo 'import numpy as np' > foo.py
~$ echo 'print(np.__version__)' >> foo.py
~$ python3 foo.py
```

Here I have the good answer from my script:

```
1.14.5
```

Now let's try in my github folder

```
~$ cd github/the/path/of/my/utils/git/folder
github/the/path/of/my/utils/git/folder$ echo 'import numpy as np' > foo.py
github/the/path/of/my/utils/git/folder$ echo 'print(np.__version__)' >> foo.py
```

And we do exactly the same :

```
github/the/path/of/my/utils/git/folder$ python3 foo.py
```

I have got these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
SystemError: initialization of multiarray raised unreported exception
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 21, in <module>
    from urllib.request import urlopen
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 88, in <module>
    import http.client
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email._policybase import compat32
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/_policybase.py", line 9, in <module>
    from email.utils import _has_surrogates
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/utils.py", line 33, in <module>
    from email._parseaddr import quote
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/email/_parseaddr.py", line 16, in <module>
    import time, calendar
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/calendar.py", line 50, in <module>
    class _localized_month:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/calendar.py", line 52, in _localized_month
    _months = [datetime.date(2001, i+1, 1).strftime for i in range(12)]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/calendar.py", line 52, in <listcomp>
    _months = [datetime.date(2001, i+1, 1).strftime for i in range(12)]
AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'date'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/home/my_user_name/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
SystemError: initialization of multiarray raised unreported exception
```

I really don't now what to do ?
Do have any ideas ?

I have already try:

```
pip install numpy -U
```

and :

```
rm -r __pycache__
```

Doesn't help...
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it was written here:

```
AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'date'
```

I just have a script named datetime.py (like the lib) in my utils folder.
I have rename the file and it works now.